# How can I automatically sync files from local system to development environment

Tags: windows, sync

I'm looking for a good <strike>Windows tool</strike> way that allows me to automatically copy files from my local pc to a development environment on a different server.
I only want to copy certain files (aspx, ascx, resx) within a directory and copy should automatically occur when I do a save on the local pc.

The way I'm doing this now is manually and sometimes with Beyond compare

Comment: What are your development environment.

Comment: What are you using for a code repository?  You can set up some (Like TFS) to automatically deploy on check-in, and I believe there are some that will check-in when a file is updated in the file system (I believe git does this, but don't quite me)

Comment: I'm using Sourcesafe and could configure it to deploy the files at check in, but since I don't have and can't run IIS on my local pc to test them, I'm using the dev environment to test the files directly and I often want to test it once I save the local file.

Comment: @Mark I rephrased your question a little bit. Looking for a tool is considered as a "Shopping recommendation" and tent to get closed as off-topic someday. Just ask in a more general way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often use [WinScp](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php) in **Keep remote directory up to date** mode.
You could specify file extension to update.
You could use it with multiple path when you use more than one tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in (filelist.txt) do xcopy /D /I /S /E /H /Q /Y /Z "%%F" "C:\Project\"
```

filelist.txt - file and folder list.

/D:m-d-y Copies files changed on or after the specified date. If no date is given, copies only those files whose source time is newer than the destination time.

/I If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory.

/Q Does not display file names while copying

Autorun autosync?

NTFS Audit event -> [LogParser](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910447) -> MSSQL (Stored Procedures (... xp_cmdshell ...))

or use

[WMI Event](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28226/Creating-WMI-Permanent-Event-Subscriptions-Using-M)